# DCCA clustering algorithm understanding

Tags: self-study, clustering, algorithms, hierarchical-clustering

I try to understand the step 2.5 of the DCCA clustering algorithm pasted below. The original reference is [here](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/24/11/1359.long) and the PowerPoint presentation is [here](https://www.google.si/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDkQFjAGahUKEwjqv7CKgMzHAhWG33IKHbV7D4w&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvc.cs.nthu.edu.tw%2Fhome%2Fpaper%2Fcodfiles%2Ftychiu%2F200904160953%2FDivisive%2520Correlation%2520Clustering%2520Algorithm%2520(DCCA)%2520for%2520grouping%2520of%2520genes%2520-%2520detecting%2520varying%2520patterns%2520in%2520expression%2520profiles.ppt&ei=23HgVapmhr_LA7X3veAI&usg=AFQjCNFiALteibZ8qsX9bMXtKjGkZf1eaQ&sig2=BCiq8_nN7ZEvReykQLF-9Q). I have the following questions:

- Do we perform step 2.5 for each variable (gene) in the dataset?
- What exactly is $AVGC_{pk}$ and what exactly $AVGC_{qk}$

The algorithm goes as follows.

1. Initially, consider all the genes in one cluster. Set number of cluster $K = 1$.
2. For each iteration, do:

   2.1 For each cluster $C_p$ calculate Pearson correlation coefficient between all pairs of genes in $C_p$.

   2.2 If no repulsion (if correlation between two variables is negative then there is *repulsion* between variables) exists between a pair of genes inside any cluster then STOP, otherwise perform Step 2.3.

   2.3 Identify a cluster $C$ for which a pair of genes $x_i, x_j$ have the most negative repulsion value among all the clusters.

   2.4 Replace cluster $C$ with two clusters $C_p$ and $C_q$, and increase number of clusters $K$ by one. Place gene $x_i$ to $C_p$ and $x_j$ to $C_q$. For all the other genes $x_k$ in $C$, compare $Cor(x_i, x_k)$ and $Cor(x_j, x_k)$. If $Cor(x_i, x_k) > Cor(x_j, x_k)$ then place $x_k$ to $C_p$, otherwise place $x_k$ to $C_q$.

   2.5 For each $x_k$ in $X$, do:

   a) For each cluster $C_p$, $1 \leq p \leq K$, calculate average correlation value $AVGC_{pk}$.

   b) If $AVGC_{pk} > AVGC_{qk}$, for each $q$, $1 \leq q \leq K$, and $p \neq q$ then place a copy of $x_k$ to new $p$ cluster $CNEW_p$.